# UIStackView within UITableVie as a cell. The stack view contents gets truncated

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uistackview

I have added these lines on the `viewDidLoad()`, hoping that maybe the cell size is not being calculated correctly. But that does not seem like it. Except the first label, rest are all truncated. Is it a limitation with the `UIStackView` or am I missing constraints?

PS. All the labels within the stack view are constrained by `UIStackView` itself.

```
   self.reportSummaryTableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
   self.reportSummaryTableView.estimatedRowHeight = 600
```

[This is the xib for the cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r7xvN.png)

[This the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aWd0Z.png)

Comment: Is that a table view inside a scroll view?

Comment: Yes. And the stack view is inside table view cell

Answer (score 0):

Try implementing UITableViewDelegate method, heightForRowAt in order to set height of a row:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
return 600
}
```